# Why does SwiftUI include two lists when using ZStack in iOS15?

Tags: ios, swiftui

1. Create new List.
2. Using ZStack with overlay effects.

[image]

Comment: Cause UIKit is still better choice :D

Comment: Yep! That right

Answer (score 1):

Your composition is wrong. If you want an overlay on the `List`, you should call `.overlay(...)` on the `List` (obviously).

```
List(...) {
    ...
}
.listStyle(.plain)
.overlay(...)
```

If you want `ZStack` with `List` and `EmptyView` (which manifests the absence of view, so your scenario looks very weird), you should include `List` into `ZStack`:

```
ZStack {
    List(...) {
        ...
    }
    .listStyle(.plain)
    EmptyView()
}
```

What is done in your code is composing `ZStack` with the output of `navigationTitle(...)` into a group of two views without a definitive layout and then injecting that group into a `NavigationView` which leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I mean there are two lists because there was no problem before iOS 15.

Comment: Yep, and what I mean is that it's weird that there was no problem.

Comment: Thank you, you helped me solve the problem. ZStackEmptyView inside commented `self`, it works!

Comment: Then, don’t you think it’s worth to accept the answer?